# Hibernate Criteria Restrictions.eq is case insensitive

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, case-insensitive, restrictions

I am using criteria to check if username and password from json are correct. I am sure that input username and password are in correct case but it always returns me object even if the letter case are different.

```
public Admin getLoggedAdminInformation(String username, String password){

   Criteria criteria = criteria()
            .add(Restrictions.eq("userName", username))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));

   return (Admin) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: have you tested your query directly in your database SQL console ? (what database it is, and what is the SQL column type by the way ?) It could be that your database is case insensitive when comparing.

Answer (score 1):

`Restrictions.eq`  just return a `SimpleExpression` object with `ignoreCase` is false.
So it will create the SQL with the exact same value that you provided.

```
public static SimpleExpression eq(String propertyName, Object value) {
        return new SimpleExpression(propertyName, value, "=");
    }
```

So this case insensitive comparison is a behavior of the database. it depends on the database server or table or column configuration.

Ex: in MS SQL server, this is based on the collation of the database, can be overrrieden in table level or column level.
sample collation name is Latin1_General_CI_AS , here CI = Case insensitive,AS = accent sensitive.